# sqlalchemy query duration logging

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My apologies if this has already been asked, but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I'm looking for the best way to log the duration of queries from sqlalchemy to syslog.

I've read this: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#configuring-logging and I've read about the sqlalchemy signals, but I'm not sure they're fit for what I'm trying to do. The echo and echo_pool flags seem to just log to stdout? I'd like more information than what they provide, too. In my perfect world, for each query, I could get the query string, the duration of the query, and even the python stack trace.

We use sqlalchemy in a couple different ways: We use the ORM, we use the query builder, and we even use text queries passed to execute. If there's a signal that would trip a function no matter which way sqlalchemy is used, that would be perfect.

I was also thinking of finding where in the code it actually sends the query over the wire, and if someone had some insight there, that would be great too.

The more I think about it, the more I think it might not be worth the effort if it's a pain, but if someone out there knew of a hook that could save the day, I thought I'd ask. For the record, I'm using Flask with the Flask-Sqlalchemy extension.

Please let me know if anything is unclear here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flask-SQLAlchemy already records information about each query when in debug mode (or when the option is set otherwise).  You can get at it with [`get_debug_queries()`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.get_debug_queries).

If you are using [Flask-DebugToolbar](http://flask-debugtoolbar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), it provides an overlay to let you explore this data for each request.

If you want to log this, you could add a function to trigger after every request that will record this info.

```
@app.after_request
def record_queries(response):
    for info in get_debug_queries():
        # write to syslog here

    return response
```